# how do i subtract row pairs in the same table in sql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table called `activity` that contains values like the following:

```
userId |      timestamp      | action
----------------------------------------
1      | 2022-10-18 10:00:00 | OPEN
2      | 2022-10-18 10:20:00 | OPEN
1      | 2022-10-18 10:05:00 | CLOSE
2      | 2022-10-18 10:22:00 | CLOSE
...
```

I want to be able to get the difference between the open and close time per user for a given day like so:

```
desiredTable
------------------------------------------------------
userId |     start_time      | time_elapsed_in_minutes
------------------------------------------------------
1      | 2022-10-18 10:00:00 | 5
2      | 2022-10-18 10:20:00 | 2
```

A couple of things to note are:

1. There is no guarantee `OPEN` and `CLOSE` rows will be back to back to each other as the table also holds a lot of other action types.
2. Also, there is no guarantee that there will be the same number of
   `OPEN` and `CLOSE` rows due to network conditions that could result in either not being reported. I.e: user 1 can have 3 opens and 1 close, so only 1 pair needs to be calculated.

**My approach**:

- create table of OPEN and CLOSE counts per user
- `userId | # opens | # closes`
- determine which number is less (# opens or # closes) and get that # of rows from the activity table
- opens table with the # of rows determined above

  - `userId | timestamp`
- closes table with the # of rows determined above

  - `userId | timestamp`
- subtract close timestamp from open timestamp group by userId and truncate to minutes

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please also include your current query attempt

Comment: Can you "the" difference between open and close, are you assuming that there is only one open/close per day? What output are you looking for if there are several per day.

Comment: Also a couple of other details. If there is a sequence of open-open-open-close which open do you use. If there is a sequence like open-open-close-close do you treat it like just one interval, overlapping, or nested?  If open is on one day and close on the next which day do you assign to the result?

Comment: @Stu I haven't started the query yet, but listed my approach above

Comment: It would be useful to include a wider set of sample data, including edge cases where the open/closes do not align and provide results to explain how the edge cases should be handled.

Comment: @RobertHamilton There is no limit to the number of opens and closes a user can have a day since they represent how many times a user opens and closes the app. 

"If there is a sequence of open-open-open-close which open do you use"
it would have to be the open event closest to the close event in terms of time, so the third open.

Comment: @AdityaMohile since you have not started your sql it is not entirely appropriate to write it out yet, but some info might be helpful:  your requirement can be stated "if the action is close and the latest previous action for the same user is open then calculate the time difference." This translates directly into a lag() window function. If you are still having trouble, update the question and I'll post an example as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74130189/how-do-i-subtract-row-pairs-in-the-same-table-in-sql#comment130883785_74130189) by [@Robert Hamilton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5774387/robert-hamilton) this can be directly translated into a query using [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html):

```sql
select  userId, 
        start_time, 
        floor(extract('epoch' from duration)/60) duration_in_minutes
from (
    select  userId,
            timestamp as start_time,
            case when action='CLOSE' and (lag(action)    over w1)='OPEN'
                 then timestamp        - (lag(timestamp) over w1)
            end as duration
  from activity
  window w1 as (partition by userId order by timestamp)) a
where duration is not null;
```

[Fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/0EN6gHmA)

But the same thing can be achieved using very basic constructs - I used [CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html)s below only for readability:

```sql
with 
"nearest_close_after_each_open" as 
    ( select 
        open.userId,
        open.timestamp as start_time,
        min(close.timestamp) as end_time 
      from activity as close
        inner join activity as open
            on open.action='OPEN' and close.action='CLOSE'
            and open.userId=close.userId
            and open.timestamp < close.timestamp 
      group by 1,2),
"longest_open_window_before_a_close" as
    ( select 
        userId, 
        end_time,
        min(start_time) as start_time 
      from nearest_close_after_each_open
      group by 1,2),
"shortest_open_window_before_a_close" as
    ( select 
        userId, 
        end_time,
        max(start_time) as start_time 
      from nearest_close_after_each_open
      group by 1,2)  
select 
  userId,
  start_time,
  end_time,
  floor(extract('epoch' from end_time-start_time )/60) as time_elapsed_in_minutes
from "shortest_open_window_before_a_close";
--from "longest_open_window_before_a_close";
```

[Fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/oFFgNaCr)

I'd normally expect all following `OPEN`s in a sequence to be retransmissions of the first one, similar to what you assume about `CLOSE`s, which is why I also added `longest_open_window_before_a_close` - pairing up the earliest recorded `OPEN` before a `CLOSE`. By default, the code uses `shortest_open_window_before_a_close` of [your choice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74130189/how-do-i-subtract-row-pairs-in-the-same-table-in-sql#comment130883248_74130189).

One unaddressed detail I spotted is

> difference between the open and close time per user **for a given
> day**

Which I think would mean all open windows should be cut off at midnight and all orphaned `CLOSES` on the following date should be assumed to have opened at midnight.

Comment: I apologize for the late reply, but I like this implementation best since it clearly accounts for the constraints. After playing around with it on Fiddle, I can confirm you are making the correct assumptions with multiple "OPEN" or "CLOSE" events in succession being a re-transmission of the first. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @AdityaMohile I'm glad it works for you. What about the "for a given day" part? Did you end up tolerating sessions that span multiple dates?

Answer (score 0):

We group every `action = 'close'` with the `action = 'open'` that comes before it. Then we group by id and choose the timestamps.

```
select    userid
         ,min(timestamp)                as start_time
         ,max(timestamp)-min(timestamp) as time_elapsed_in_minutes
from     (
          select  *
                  ,count(case action when 'OPEN' then 1 end) over(partition by userid order by timestamp) as grp
          from   t
          where  action in('OPEN', 'CLOSE')
          ) t
group by  userid, grp
```

| userid | start_time | time_elapsed_in_minutes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-10-18 10:00:00 | 00:05:00 |
| 2 | 2022-10-18 10:20:00 | 00:02:00 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/qIhSpBpa)

Comment: I can't help but appreciate your use of a window function with a conditional count, [not all results this code returns are correct](https://dbfiddle.uk/jb8kTKy_). 1. Two leading orphaned `CLOSE`s will be returned as an open window. 2. An open window closes on the latest [instead of the earliest `CLOSE`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74130189/how-do-i-subtract-row-pairs-in-the-same-table-in-sql#comment130883248_74130189).

Comment: He specifically mentioned a few opens on a row and not a few close. That makes both my solutions correct.

Comment: Also, if that was the case it would  still be easily fixable in both my solutions. If the op says it what he wants then I'll update both of them.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `lead()` when next `action` is `closed`.

```
select    * 
from     (
          select   userid
                  ,timestamp                                                                                                                                                   as start_time
                  ,case lead(action) over(partition by userid order by timestamp) when 'CLOSE' then lead(timestamp) over(partition by userid order by timestamp)-timestamp end as time_elapsed_in_minutes
          from   t
          where  action in('OPEN', 'CLOSE')
          ) t
where     time_elapsed_in_minutes is not null
```

| userid | start_time | time_elapsed_in_minutes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-10-18 10:00:00 | 00:05:00 |
| 2 | 2022-10-18 10:20:00 | 00:02:00 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/QNLXf75O)

Comment: While this does work on the small sample, [it's easy to break](https://dbfiddle.uk/qLic4oUy).

Comment: See my other comment